# How to get data from this type of JSON response using retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit

This is JSON response:

```json
    {
        "0": {
            "userId": "8888888888",
            "Long": "77.28717",
            "Lat": "28.63864",
            "time": "14:14:47",
            "date": "2020-12-19"
        },
        "1": {
            "userId": "8888888888",
            "Long": "77.28141",
            "Lat": "28.63602",
            "time": "14:10:05",
            "date": "2020-12-19"
        },
        "2": {
            "userId": "8888888888",
            "Long": "77.28716",
            "Lat": "28.63863",
            "time": "14:09:40",
            "date": "2020-12-19"
        },
        "status": "success"
    }
```

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: Add more details

Answer (score 0):

[Retrofit](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23)

This can help you. You have to try.

Comment: its not 0 to 3 value it has 1000 value then how can handle this.

Comment: with pojo classes,because it has created seprate class for each.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link for create pojo class for retrofit response. [create here your class.](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

1. paste your response here and select other option you want like serializable , parcalble etc.
2. then give your package name and class name .
3. then download zip from there and add to your project.

here is example for your class.

[image: here is example for your class.]

[Here is full example for calling API through retrofit.](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial)